# Redshift table not populating from Parquet file

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

[image]I tried to create an external table in Redshift and populate it from a parquet file. The table creation is successful, but it doesn't get populated at all although the parquet file is not empty.

[image: Query results]

Comment: Something is clearly wrong! However, you have not provided any information that we can use to assist you. I would suggest starting with a simple Parquet file created by an ['UNLOAD'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD_command_examples.html#unload-examples-partitioned-parquet) statement to try and get something working. Then, try to figure out why the above table isn't working. It might be due to an incorrect file format, or something wrong in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: i will add the code i used to create the table.

Comment: We cannot reproduce your situation because we do not have the Parquet file, nor access to your S3 bucket. There is nothing we can do to assist you given the above information. You'll need to start simple (eg with a different Parquet) file and work up to your current situation.

Comment: i tried with other files and it works just fine it's just with this file that i am getting this issue. i even tried by gradually increasing the column name and still facing this issue.

Comment: Do you have another system that can read that Parquet file, just to make sure it hasn't been corrupted?